# property file values are not mapped to the correct data type in spring jersey junit

Tags: java, spring, junit, jersey-2.0

In my spring application context file, some beans property values are loaded from property files outside the war.

**Property file:**
    11

**bean.xml**

```
<bean id="constants" class="com.uniphore.util.Constants">
        <property name="flag" value="${flag}" />
</bean>
```

**Constant.java**

```
public class Constants {
       private int flag;
       //Getters and setters
}
```

If i map this values as int in my bean class its worked in normal way of executing.But if i run using junit i get the NumberFormatException

Below is my applicationContext object creation part:

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.setContextPath("/");
context.getInitParams().put("contextConfigLocation", applicationResourcePath);

ContextLoaderListener listener = new ContextLoaderListener();
RequestContextListener requestlistener = new RequestContextListener();
context.addEventListener(requestlistener);
context.addEventListener(listener);
jettyServer.setHandler(context);

ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*");
jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);
//jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", clazz.getCanonicalName());
jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "com.uniphore");
jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.beanValidation.enableOutputValidationErrorEntity.server", "true");
```

Above configuration is correct or not?

Please help me to fix this issue.Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!